# Screen detection and mouse reverse (x & y axis) kali linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I installed kali linux OS on my laptop.

The installation went well but when I booted in kali linux the screen was backwards. I signed in as root and the screen flipped back but the mouse is reverse (x & y axis).

When I move my mouse left it moves right when I move it down it moves up. If I want to press a button at the upper right I need to press it at the down left.

The screen is acting backwordes (x & y axis)but I see the graphics straight and the mouse is acting backwordes.

I installed kali linux again with a fresh installation. I have the same problem as before.

I installed kali linux again with a fresh installation. I have the same problem as before.

- I searched the web And I don't find information on a problem like this

Comment: Use `xrandr --verbose` to check for a "mirroring" transformation of the screen (-1 in matrix), and `xinput` to find your mouse id followed by `xinput --list-props <id>` to find a "mirroring" transformation for your mouse. If you find any, we still don't know the reason it activates, but at least you can fix it.

Comment: @sara Did you check about transformation matrix? Give some update ... It is an interesting issue.

Comment: I will check about transformation matrix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per @dirkt suggestion you can use transformation matrix to correct up things.

First, to see what is the current settings of transformation matrix you can run:

```
xinput
#locate the device ids that do not work correctly
xinput list-props devid |grep Matrix
#replace devid with your device number.
```

If everything was working ok Matrix should like this:
`1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 #case normal`

If you ever wanted to force mouse/screen to be reversed, then you should apply a matrix like this:
`-1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1 #case inverted`

I suppose your mouse/screen since they work inverted , their `xinput list-props |grep Matrix` should look like "case inverted" instead of "case normal"

In this case, force those devices to use normal case matrix like this:
`xinput set-prop devicename Coordinate Transformation Matrix 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 #be sure to use the exact device name as it is reported by xinput`

Now you should be ok.

I don't know what is the reason that wrong matrix has been applied in your devices, but i think is better to file a bug to Kali people for this behavior.

If the screen display is inverted , then xrandr should be enough :
`xrandr --output yourscreen --rotate normal`

If your screen is a touchscreen then xrandr rotate is not enough. You need to apply correct transformation matrix in your touchscreen as well in order touches to be sensed in correct position.

Comment: I will try this. I hope that this solution will work.

Comment: Well...? How did that go?

Comment: I tried xrandr --output your screen --rotate normal. it worked. When I move the mouse it moves to the right place. but I see the screen display rotated(180 degrees). Another problem is that when I click the mouse it clicks it in the wrong place.for example if I click the mouse on the right top it will detect the click at the bottom left. xinput is not recognized.

Comment: @sara apt-get install xinput and retry. Screen and mouse should xave the same matrix.

Comment: I will work on it. How do I change mouse matrix?

Comment: As i describe in my answer with xinput set-prop  but you need to provide device id of your mouse. If you don't use xinput it will not work correctly. XRANDR os not enough.

Comment: xinput package is missing

Comment: @sara You can install it with apt-get install.

Comment: I tried.Its missing.

Comment: @sara In this link, https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?19911-Disabling-touch-screen-in-Kali-Linux  people disabled a touchscreen device using xinput.... xinput is a basic xorg/X11  package and should be available in your repos.... what error do you get for xinput installation??

Comment: My coordinate matrix is ok but when I slide the touchpad to the right, it moves to the left and vice-versa. Also, my touchpad seems really sensitive. Whenever I start typing, the cursor will be placed(randomly) in different places and writing starts messing up. Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

Here's exactly how I fixed this problem:
Typing
`xinput`, into your console will print out a list of inputs like this:

```
? Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
?   ? Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
?   ? USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
?   ? ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
? Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ? Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ? Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ? Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ? Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ? Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ? USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ? Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ? AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

(Your experience may vary per devices)

Note that the id=# is the device id you're actually looking for.

I wasn't sure which device was being screwy, so I went through each one. Turns out, device 11 was being dumb! To list the properties, type:

`xinput list-props 11` (Because device id=11 was the problem device)

Typing that in will show something like...

```
Device 'USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller':
  Device Enabled (139): 1
  Coordinate Transformation Matrix (141):   -1.000000, 0.000000, -1.000000, 0.000000, -1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, -1.000000
  libinput Calibration Matrix (276):    1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
  libinput Calibration Matrix Default (277):    1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
  libinput Send Events Modes Available (259):   1, 0
  libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (260):  0, 0
  libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (261):  0, 0
  Device Node (262):    "/dev/input/event10"
  Device Product ID (263):  1111, 4238
```

(I'm writing this after having fixed the problem, so the -1.000000 values may have been elsewhere)
Those "-1.000000" values are the problem. To set those to the correct values,
I typed:

```
xinput set-prop 11 "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

Then I rebooted, and all was well!

I don't know why this is still a problem. It's been logged on bugs.kali.org more than once, and each one is marked as closed, with resolution being "won't fix".

Comment: I was reading about this problem a lot. This is a bug. you can find the problem that caused it. I'm not sure if it's connected but I think that my problem has caused because I was using a PC that's running 64 bit and I messed up with the partition disk settings , that caused that I could only install the 32 bit version of Kali Linux. The solution I found was to reset the partition disk settings and then I reinstalled to the 64 bit version of Kali Linux.

Comment: You could always change the settings of the screen as you did:)

Comment: This worked not the selected answer!