# Invert screen and invert mouse on my Kali Linux live(debian) latest

Tags: debian, kali-linux, configuration, display

After installing Kali Linux live (debian) on my USB drive. on running the display was inverted same as the mouse I have tried some basic commands like `xrandr` but not available.

Comment: Apparently your capslock got inverted also.

Comment: You mean the display is upside-down? Or mirrored? Or the colours are inverted (but then, I wonder that that means for the mouse...)? What is an "inverted mouse"?

Comment: have you tried the key combo ctrl+alt+up-arrow? or down arrow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Screen detection and mouse reverse (x & y axis) kali linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328248/screen-detection-and-mouse-reverse-x-y-axis-kali-linux)